# How to find whether variable is Object array or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement to find whether variable is Object array or not, below is the example data:

```
var myColumnDefs = [
                        {key:"label", sortable:true, resizeable:true},
                        {key:"notes", sortable:true,resizeable:true}];
```

If I do

> jQuery.type(myColumnDefs) then it will say it's an **array**

but how can i find whether it's object array or not?

If I iterate each element in array and check for object with **jQuery.isPlainObject()** then also it won't work because it will check only for plain objects like **jQuery.isPlainObject({})**.

Comment: object array... as opposed to an array of numbers? or...

Comment: Use `typeof` like `if( (typeof myColumnDefs === "object")`. Or `myColumnDefs instanceof Object` that will return true or false

Comment: in JavaScript, all arrays are objects. what do you mean when you say 'object array'?

Comment: Or maybe instanceof ...

Comment: I think he wants to know whether the array contains objects as opposed to numbers, strings, or a combination of objects and other types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays in javascript aren't typed, and so you will have to check each that each and every element of the array is an object.

For instance:

```
var isObjectArray = true;
myColumnDefs.forEach(function(elem) {
  if (typeof elem === "object")
    isObjectArray = false;
});
```

Here is a re-usable function:

```
function isObjectArray(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      if (typeof arr[i] !== "object")
         return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: may as well break on that condition too

Comment: Agreed, I've changed that in the function I added - I'm used to lazy languages such as Haskell.

Comment: Hi @ChiranjeeviIT, could you accept my answer as correct by clicking the 'tick' next to it?